# How can I combine these Set<? extends Vector> filtering functions for my API?

Tags: java, api, generics, set, hashset

I have two functions that I am using to filter two different Sets of `? extends Vector`, but I do not know how, or if I can combine this method to take any kind of object that extends Vector.

`BlockVector.class` and `BaseBlock.class` both extend `Vector.class`

```
public static HashSet<BlockVector> filterBlockVectorSet(Set<BlockVector> set,
        String playerName) {
    HashSet<BlockVector> filtered = new HashSet<BlockVector>();
    for (BlockVector v : set) {
        if (v != null && Mongo.hasTrust(v.getX(), v.getZ(), playerName)) {
            filtered.add(v);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
public static HashSet<BaseBlock> filterBaseBlockSet(HashSet<BaseBlock> set,
        String playerName) {
    HashSet<BaseBlock> filtered = new HashSet<BaseBlock>();
    for (BaseBlock v : set) {
        if (v != null && Mongo.hasTrust(v.getX(), v.getZ(), playerName)) {
            filtered.add(v);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

This is something I came up with that is valid according to eclipse:

```
public static HashSet<? extends Vector> filterVectorSet(HashSet<? extends Vector> set,
        String playerName) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    HashSet<? extends Vector> filtered = (HashSet<? extends Vector>) set.clone();
    for (Vector v : set) {
        if (v != null && Mongo.hasTrust(v.getX(), v.getZ(), playerName)) {
        }else{
            filtered.remove(v);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: Does it work as you expect?

Comment: Yes it does work as I expected, I just got around to debugging it in my application.
On the other end I use a `blocks = (HashSet<BlockVector>) ArtboardAPI.filterVectorSet(blocks, playerName);` with another `@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })`

Comment: There's just a strong opinion around here that Stack Overflow is  supposed to deal with problems, while another site - [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - is more suited for possible improvements to the working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a generic method:

```
public static <T extends Vector> HashSet<T> filterVectorSet(HashSet<T> set,
        String playerName) {
    HashSet<T> filtered = new HashSet<T>();
    for (T v : set) {
        if (v != null && Mongo.hasTrust(v.getX(), v.getZ(), playerName)) {
            filtered.add(v);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to using this as soon as I can. It looks exactly like what I think I'm looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to see if I can use generics for a lot of the other projects I have.